# IOS swipe down spotlight menu in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, html

Is it possible to make the IOS swipe down spotlight menu as shown below using HTML5 and JavaScript?

http://cdn.macrumors.com/article-new/2013/07/searchoption.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `collapse` from bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Show spotlight
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <input type="text" id="spotlight">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Of course this requires your page to include twitter bootstrap

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KbQyx/14/ .I dont know how I can proceed with this? I was thinking more having the search bar appear when swipping the down.